# Soft keyboard shows a "Go" button instead of a "Search" button when entering some text in a SearchView widget

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-softkeyboard, searchview

I have followed [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) to configure a searchview widget in the action bar. Almost everything works fine, except for the fact that the soft keyboard doesn't show the right button. Instead of showing a "Search" button the keyboard shows a "Go" button and it also takes me to another activity, which I'm sure it can't be right.

[image]

**Do you have any idea how to make the keyboard show a "search" button**? also why do we have to put this code in the searchable activities:

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's pretty easy. However, I'm not really sure why it doesn't show the right button by default:

Anyway, here's what you need to do:

In your searchable configuration add this line :

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
```

So that you have something similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:label="@string/search_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"/>
```

I'm sure that should fix your problem, but as I mentioned I'm not sure why the "search" button isn't shown right from the start.

Answer (score 7):

Use this one

```
  searchview.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
```

Look at this Tutorial it will solve your second problem of the intent filter understanding
[Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I don't have any EditText :(

Comment: It gives this warning "Call requires API level 14 (current min is 11): android.widget.SearchView#setImeOptions"

Comment: Ok now I'm certain that this is because I need to manually set the imeOptions, but do you have any idea why this isn't done automatically? Before I tried to show the searchview widget in the action bar I put the searchview directly in the activity and I didn't have any problem with the buttons in the keyboard :S

Comment: can you please give your manifest code ,while these types of anomalies comes while we developing so don't get it nervous bro.

Comment: There is not any error or something i have found when i checked your issue on my platform

Comment: here is my manifest https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AE0A09BAC8F588B!294&authkey=!ALSqOmme-EVja_I&ithint=file%2cxml

Answer (score 2):

Try getting your SearchView and calling following method:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: This only shows a submit button in the action bar, but doesn't change the button in the soft keyboard